# MAJ a sql server DB from excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a Sql Server database and I need to update it every day by adding temporary tables (from excel) and compare them with existing tables, then add the lines that do not exist.
Can you help me ?

Comment: Please use English when asking a question: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: Look into ETL.  This stands for Extract, Transform and Load.  It is a way of processing data.  The ETL tool that comes with SQL Server is called SSIS.  This is designed for just this type of work.